# Javascript: Generate large table in DOM asynchronously.

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, settimeout

I am trying to create a large table in IE 9 with the following code on click of button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#generateTable").click(function() {
            generateTable1();
        });
    });

    function generateTable() {

    $('#sampletable').html("");
        try {
            var content = "<table border=1>"

            for (j = 0; j < 360; j++) {

                content += '<tr>';
                for (i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
                    content += '<td>' + j + '</td>';
                }
                content += '</tr>';

            }

            content += "</table>"
            $('#sampletable').html(content);
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }
```

As expected IE is getting chocked / hanged while creating this table. So I want to create this table asynchronously using JavaScript asyn pattern (I guess building table in chucks using settimeout method...).

How to make this generateTable() call asynchronous ?

Comment: It might be worth trying to generate the table using `document.createElement` instead of a string. It will probably perform much better. The code does still generate over a million `td` elements, and I don't really see why you'd need that.

Comment: Few questions: 1) Do you always know the size the table is going to be?  If so, why not generate it statically? 2)  What's the table used for? 3) Is it only IE 9 that has this problem? Do other browsers exhibit it? 4) What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @GEORGESTOCKET yes i will know the size of the table. I cannot generate it statically statically because I have to evaluation several things while painting each cell. More over I am getting the data for the table from the server as 2D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I have written. This code adds the row in the table in chunks and therefore browser do not hangs.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#generateTable").click(function() {
                generateTable();
            });
        });

        function generateTable() {
        // Initialize a few things here...

        var batchSize = 2;
        var rowNum = 365;
        var totalRow = 0;
        $('#reportTable').hide();

        var buildTableAsync = function(batchSize) {
            var content;
            var processedRow = 0;

            while (processedRow < batchSize) {
                content += "<tr>";
                for ( var i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
                    content += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
                }
                content += "</tr>";
                processedRow++;
                totalRow++;
            }
            $('#reportTable').append(content);
            if (totalRow < rowNum) {

                setTimeout(function() {
                    doOneFactorialStep(batchSize);
                }, 1);
            } else {

            $('#reportTable').show();
            }
        };
        buildTableAsync(batchSize);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Rendering the table is probably what's causing the bad performance, not the generation of it. If you do it asynchronously, it may make it worse since the browser would need to constantly run the table column sizing algorithm and reflow and repaint the table (although it may be better than causing a long running script warning).

Try making the table fixed layout and explicitly set the widths of the columns so it doesn't have to run column sizing. Is pagination an option? Pretty sure nobody's gonna want to see a million cells at once. You may also look at plugins that do virtual scrolling.

Comment: If the table is set to fixed at start and then upon completion of adding in data this can be removed. It should technically work out better, but its going to stutter visually once completed.